# Custom message box must wait for user input and not allow user to pass without inputting input

Tags: vb.net

l would like to create a message box so l would like the message box not disappear until l input the result
can anyone help? So l would like the message box to not disappear until the user inputs an input
so l have designed the custom message box because l would like it to have my own design l could use the system one but it not to my liking in terms of design[Find the attached image of the custom message box

```
Public Class Exit_Mssg_Box

    Private Sub BtnYes_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnYes.Click
        Application.Exit()
    End Sub

    Private Sub BtnNo_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnNo.Click
        Me.Hide()
    End Sub

    Private Sub BtnCancel_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnCancel.Click
        Me.Hide()
    End Sub
End Class
```

[image: 1]

I am sought of new to this please help guys
the problem is that if one moves to taskbar one can select login form so the message box of the winform application will be sent back.

Comment: Is this in WinForms?  You can set the border style to none or put a cancel in the form terminate, if so.

Comment: Why would the form disappear for no reason? What's the actual problem here? None has been expressed.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need to create your own message box.

```
Private Sub OPCode()
    Dim dr = MessageBox.Show("Choose a button", "My MessageBox Title", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel)
    Select Case dr
        Case DialogResult.Yes
            End
        Case DialogResult.No
            Hide()
        Case DialogResult.Cancel
            Hide()
    End Select
End Sub
```